# why collectionViewCells are not displaying in iOS?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Hi i can getting the image from gallery but collectionViewCells are not displaying on UI.i drag and drop the collectionView gave connections to delegate and datasourse methods.but why did not get CollectionViewCells.I have written code like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  
{ 
imagesArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"]; 
}   

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info  
{ 
inputImage= info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; [imagesArray addObject:inputImage];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} 

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView; {
return 1;
} 

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
return [imagesArray count];
} 

- (MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(!cell) { 
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image =[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
[collectionView reloadData];
return cell;
}
```

please anybody suggest me how to do this.help is appreciated

Comment: Did you make your cell in a xib file, not the storyboard?

Comment: add subview of recipeImageView  into cell.[cell.contentview addsubview:recipeImageView ];

Comment: i made cell in .xib rdelmar

Comment: Is recipeImageView non-nil if you log it?

Comment: yes it gives non-nil ..i can getting images in the form of NSmutableArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have `imageArray` with data. And try to reload `collectionView` in `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` Method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
 imagesArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
 [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"]; 
      }  

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { 

inputImage= info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
[imagesArray addObject:inputImage];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView; {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
return [imagesArray count];
} 

- (MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(!cell) { 
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image =[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're calling reloadData in cellForItemAtIndexPath. That will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Thankyou soo much for giving nice answer  

rdelmar..its working now